# Schedule an async function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, cron

I want to schedule a function which is asynchronous (async/await ruturn type) to run for every two minutes.

I tried with generic `setInterval`, node modules like **node-schedule , cron, node-cron, async-poll** but unable to achieve polling for a async function call.

This is what I tried in code:

```
cron.schedule("*/2 * * * *", await this.servicesManager.startPoll() => {
               console.log('running on every two minutes');
}); // this is not working breaks after first run
            
const job = schedule.scheduleJob(" */1 * * * *", async function() {
   try {
         return await this.ServicesManager.startPoll(); // this function startPoll is undefined when using this 
       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
   }
   console.log('Run on every minute');
});
                    
const event = schedule.scheduleJob("*/2 * * * *", this.ServicesManager.startPoll()); //using node-schedule , breaks after first time
cron.schedule("*/2 * * * *", await this.ServicesManager.startPoll()); // using cron same result as using node-schedule
return await this.ServicesManager.startPoll(); // without polling works
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
// version 1
cron.schedule("*/2 * * * *", this.servicesManager.startPoll);

// version 2 => if servicesManager needs its `this` reference
cron.schedule("*/2 * * * *", async () => this.servicesManager.startPoll());

//version 3 ==> using node-schedule
schedule.scheduleJob("*/1 * * * *", async () => this.ServicesManager.startPoll());
```

I don't know about your `servicesManager`, you might have to use "version 2" from above to get it to work.

The schedule libraries need a function to execute, but instead they get a resolved Promise in the examples above.

Comment: This is part of nodejs based rest api server code , The ServicesManager is the wrapper around fucntional calls , the controller makes the calls from ServiceManager, version 1 and 2 is not working , similar way i am trying with schedule.scheduleJob("*/1 * * * *", async () => { this.ServicesManager.startPoll(); });                                            Here , ServicesManager calls startPoll which calls another async function and startPoll itself retruns async

Comment: None of the code lines in the answer are syntactically correct.

Answer (score 4):

Scheduled asynchronous calls won't work using `node-cron` at least up to `v3.0.0`, but we can use `node-schedule` for this as follows.

JS

```
schedule.scheduleJob("*/1 * * * *", async () => await this.lifeService.addLife(userId, 1));
```

TS

```
import nodeSchedule = require("node-schedule");

const job: nodeSchedule.Job = nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * * *', async () => {
    const life = await this.lifeService.getLives(userId);
    console.log(`user's life`, life);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using **async/await** function like :

myService.ts :

```
    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
  async myExample() {
    const todaysDate: dayjs.Dayjs = dayjs();
    Logger.log(`Cron started at ${todaysDate}`);
    const users = await this.myRepo.getUsers();
   // code here
  }
```

myRepo.ts :

```
    getUsers() {
    return this.myModel.find({});
  }
```

but it was not working so changed myService.ts and tried **then** :

```
    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
  async myExample() {
    const todaysDate: dayjs.Dayjs = dayjs();
    Logger.log(`Cron started at ${todaysDate}`);
    this.myRepo.getUsers().then(users => {
      // code here
    });
  }
```