# setTimeout inside a loop, stops script from working

Tags: javascript

My script is receiving data from API and store in MongoDB automatically. I was needed to create a at least 2 second delay before receiving one data after another. The problem is that my script is stop working on second time. Let's say my script working every hour, I enable the script at 14.00 - it works and at 15.00 - it stops. I start researching the problem and come to the point that is problem with `setTimeout()` inside a loop.

This is an article what I found [Watch Out When Using `SetTimeout(`) in For Loop #JS](https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f#:~:text=setTimeout%20function%20in%20JavaScript%20usually,already%205%20when%20the%20console.)

This line is a [Node-Schedule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) It basically calls the script every 15th minutes (if someone is wondering that it is)

```
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', callIt)
```

My goal: How can I change my code to still having a 2 second's delay and working loop. Is there any alternatives to use instead of `setTimeout()`, maybe I just need to put a `setTimeout()` in another place in a code or maybe there is even some type of packages that I can add additional.

**Problematic code area:**

```
    var symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"]
];
let cnt = 0;

const callIt = () => {

    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
            cnt++;
            if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 2000)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};
```

**FULL CODE**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"]
    ];
    let cnt = 0;

    const callIt = () => {

        fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                    return {
                        Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                        High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                        Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                        Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                        Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                        Timespan: 30,
                    }
                });
                console.log(btcusdtdata);
                saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
                cnt++;
                if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 2000)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    };

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', callIt)

const saveToDatebase = function(BTCdata) {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
        const myobj = { Name: symbols[cnt - 1], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
        dbo.collection(`${symbols[cnt - 1]}`).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });

};
```

**EDIT1:**
To be more correct I'll specify the task more accurate.
My node-schedule package suppose to call the script every 15 minutes and I want to call properties in array every 2 seconds. I need to call properties from array every 2 seconds otherwise I will receive IP ban from Binance API for calling the API to much/fast.

**EDIT2**
Alright. `setInterval()` is not a solution for me. Since I need to call the script every 15 minutes it should go through array and when it call all properties from array it suppose to stop. In `setInterval()` after calling the all properties in array in starts it again, this is doesn't what I need, unfortunately.

EDIT3:
I tested few options from answers below, all of them get me to the same problem that the script cannot start the second time or the script is starts working immediately or repeats even after array properties are ended. Still thank you for answers, but my problem is still one.

Currently I trying to use async/await methods. But I receive an error that `await is only valid in async function`

**EDIT4**:
So this is a fullcode solution from @yoavmatchulsky. Script starts working, but I don't receive any data or something. It's just like working - but nothing happening. No errors, nothing.

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

const sleep = async(timeout) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

const callIt = async(symbol) => {
    return fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => async() => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            await saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};

const saveToDatebase = async function(BTCdata) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

        MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
            const myobj = { Name: symbols[cnt - 1], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
            dbo.collection(`${symbols[cnt - 1]}`).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                console.log('1 document inserted');
                db.close();
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });
};

const run = async() => {
    let cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < symbols.length) {
        await callIt(symbols[cnt]);
        await sleep(2000);
        cnt++;
    }
}

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/2 * * * *', run);
```

Comment: I wasnt able to completly follow your 3 edit - what script cannot start a second time, pls name them.

Comment: @Estradiaz my script suppose to work every hour. It works first time, but it doesn't starts second time. Cause of `setInterval()` inside a loop

Comment: @Hexycode You implemented @yoavmatchulsky's solution incorrectly. In the second `.then()` of `callIt`, you wrote `data => async() => {` - this is wrong. It's true that their solution was missing an async, but the way you fixed it makes the `.then()` return a function `async() => {...}` which is never executed. Change it to `.then(async data => {` to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this problem has been made much more complex than it needs to be. The core problem is simple: **You never reset `cnt` to 0 after the first loop**. So when the second loop starts, `cnt` is still greater than the array size, and it exits early! Let's look at fixing this problem first.

The easiest way is to change your `schedule.scheduleJob` callback to an anonymous function which resets `cnt` to 0 and then calls `callIt()` to do the recursive loop again. From your original code, this is one small change to the `scheduleJob` callback:

```
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', () => {
  cnt = 0;
  callIt();
});
```

With this, `cnt` will be reset to 0 and your code will work repeatedly correctly.

Others have pointed out that `async/await` is a good way to make this code simpler and I agree. I'll also note that you're using the callback form of your mongodb functions, but all mongodb functions also return promises. **Try the above first** to confirm it works, then if you'd like, consider the improvements below.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

//a descriptive name helps your future self and others understand code easier
const getBTCData = async symbol => {  //make this function accept the current symbol
    //async/await lets us write this much nicer and with less nested indents
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(symbol, btcusdtdata);
    //recursive functions are complicated, we can get rid of it here
    //by moving the responsibility to the caller
};

//helper function for an awaitable timeout
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', async () => {
    //expand this function to be responsible for looping the data
    for(let symbol of symbols) {
        //we can pass symbol to getBTCData instead of making it
        //responsible for figuring out which symbol it should get
        await getBTCData(symbol); 
        await sleep(2000);
    }
});

//make this a helper function so `saveToDatabase()` isn't also responsible for it
const getDateTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
};

const saveToDatebase = async (symbol, BTCdata) => {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    let dateTime = getDateTime();
    
    //use await here and below to vastly simplify this function
    let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
    const myobj = { Name: symbol, Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
    await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
    console.log('1 document inserted');
    db.close();
};
```

I haven't tested this code - let me know if there are any errors.

Comment: this is a solution! cnt was never returned to 0 . In my way, I did it with if else statement.

Comment: Hello! Thanks one more time. The code snippet gives me error here `await getBTCData(symbol);` - error  `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @Hexycode, shoot, I knew I'd forget something. I added the missing `async`, it should work now.

Comment: I was testing your code. It's working the only problem that it doesn't stores data properly. It creates a new collection in mongodb with a name of "undefined" and stores everything there instead of different collections. I'm trying to find where is the route go wrong.

Comment: I'm getting messed with symbols and symbol. In API request there is definitely need to be ${symbols[cnt]} and for (let symbol of symbols) also make a small mess cause I think mongodb doesn't store data because of it.

Comment: @Hexycode I missed two references to `symbols[cnt - 1]` in the `saveToDatabase()` function. I edited the answer to handle these correctly. They were resulting in `undefined` because `cnt` in this implementation is never anything but zero, and `symbols[-1]` is undefined. There definitely does not need to be `${symbols[cnt]}`, it is exactly equivalent to `symbol` in my version, as it's a variable pointing to that same string.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any alternatives to use instead of setTimeout()

Assuming you just want to execute some code every 2 seconds, instead of using a loop, use `setTInterval` with 2 seconds delay.

```
setInterval(() => {
   // code here will run every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

#### EDIT:

> I need to call the script every 15 minutes it should go through array
>   and when it call all properties from array it suppose to stop

Here's an example of code that calls `run` function every 15 seconds and accesses each array element with 2 seconds delay.

First `setInterval` function calls the `run` function every 15 seconds and second `setInterval` function, inside the `run` function, accesses each array element with 2 seconds delay. After all array elements have been accessed, this interval is cancelled.

```js
const symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

console.log('wait 15 seconds before run function is called');
setInterval(() => {
  run();
}, 15000);

function run() {
  console.log('running code after 15 seconds interval');
  let index = 0;
  const id = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(symbols[index]);
    index++;
    
    if (index >= symbols.length) {
      console.log('all array indexes accessed');
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: as you can see I have array in top and I wan't to call every position in array with 2 seconds interval. I'll try it up with `setInterval`

Comment: if you want to access all the array indexes whenever your code executes, then use loop inside the setInterval.

Comment: I edited the main question with more accurate goal. You can check it up in EDIT1. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Main question edited. setInterval doesn't work for me. There is explanation why.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused where correctly I should implement the code. I understand the logic behind it, but is it gonna fit with node-schedule package which is going to call the script every hour? Like in my answer

Comment: Is it possible for you provide full code solution? That I can see the logic where the things go, of course if it's possible for you. Still thanks for answer.

Comment: In the example code snippet, first `setInterval` function is playing the role of the npm package that will execute your script every hour and the second `setInterval` function is where your code should be so that when your script executes, it iterates over the array with 2 second delay between each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> Alright. setInterval() is not a solution for me. Since I need to call the script every 15 minutes it should go through array and when it call all properties from array it suppose to stop. In setInterval() after calling the all properties in array in starts it again, this is doesn't what I need, unfortunately.

Maybe it would be better.  You task runs every 15 minutes and then loops through 5 values with a 2 second delay between each.  You could have a task using setInterval() that runs every 2 seconds and watches a queue, then just add those 5 items to the queue every 15 minutes.

```js
const symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];
let queue = [];

const enqueueSymbols = () => {
  symbols.forEach(symbol => queue.push(symbol);
}

const process = () => {
  const symbol = queue.shift();
  if (!symbol) return;

  // do processing for the symbol
}

// interval will check the queue and process ONE entry every 2
// seconds if it finds one
let intervalId = setInterval(process, 2000);

// job will add the list of symbols to the queue every 15 minutes
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', enqueueSymbols);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setInterval.

setInterval(callIt, 2000);

but put it outside the callIt function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: So, I will try this as well, I will put it after .`catch((err) => {console.log(err);})};`
Thank you for advice.

Comment: Main question edited. setInterval doesn't work for me. There is explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), you can use a helper method to "sleep":

```
const sleep = async (timeout) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}
```

And then use it and your `callIt` method with an outside loop:

```
while (cnt < symbols.length) {
    await callIt();
    await sleep(2000);
}
```

just be sure to remove the `setTimeout` in `callIt`

EDIT - Full code example:

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

const sleep = async (timeout) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

const callIt = async (symbol) => {
    return fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => async {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            await saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
};

const saveToDatebase = async function(BTCdata) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

        MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
            const myobj = { Name: symbols[cnt - 1], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
            dbo.collection(`${symbols[cnt - 1]}`).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
                console.log('1 document inserted');
                db.close();
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });
};

const run = async () => {
    let cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < symbols.length) {
        await callIt(symbols[cnt]);
        await sleep(2000);
        cnt++;
    }
}

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', run);
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with it, can you provide me example if its possible how I suppose to correctly implement it in code.

Comment: I receive an error here  `await saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);`

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: I was missing an `async` declaration to the function in `then`

Comment: Are you sure that syntax is right? I will check it by myself now, but I think there is few mistakes in it, at least my VS Code shows them

Comment: There is some syntax wrong here  `.then(data => async {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {` isn't it suppose to be `async() =>`

Comment: I tested your solution. The thing is that script doesn't even start working. No errors, nothing, in console everything is fine. But when time comes for script to start(let's say every minute) it doesn't.

Comment: ok sorry. I wrote it of the top of my head I haven't tested it or ran it

Comment: no stress, still thanks for answer. Still the problem is here.

Comment: As well, I'm thinking that solution can be in stoping setTimeout. Otherwise I don't have any ideas how to deal with this annoying bug

Comment: maybe the scheduling is wrong. according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485153/schedule-an-async-function-in-nodejs, try to using something like `schedule.scheduleJob("*/15 * * * *", async () => run(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `async / await` solution:

```
const callIt = async () => {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(
      `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`
    );
    let data = await res.json();
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
      return {
        Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
        High: parseFloat(d[2]),
        Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
        Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
        Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
        Timespan: 30
      };
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
    cnt++;
    if (cnt < symbols.length) {
      await sleep(2000);
      callIt();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Testing your solution now

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same error. Script doesn't want to start second time.

Answer (score 0):

check you `saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);` function

```js
var symbols = ['ZRXBTC', 'ETHBTC', 'ETCBTC', 'KAVABTC', 'AEBTC'];
let cnt = 0;

const callIt = () => {
  console.log("count", cnt);
  fetch(
    `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${
      symbols[cnt]
    }&interval=30m&limit=1`,
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
          Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
          High: parseFloat(d[2]),
          Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
          Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
          Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
          Timespan: 30,
        };
      });
      console.log(btcusdtdata);
     // saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
      cnt++;
      if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 2000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 2000);
      console.log('Error => ', err);
    });
};

callIt();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The script starts working immediately but suppose to start working accordingly to node-schedule package

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making recursive calls you could use `forEach` and plan all `setTimeout` tasks ahead of time.

```js
var symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

symbols.forEach((symbol, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // your code here
    console.log(index, symbol);
  }, index * 2000);
});
```

Note that there is a slight difference. This will schedule the start of the tasks 2000 ms from each other. There is not 2000 ms between the tasks.

```
|> task 1 <|                |> task 2 <|
|<-------- 2000 ms -------->|
```

If you want 2000 ms between the tasks things are a bit more complicated. You'll have to manage a queue and add 2000 ms delay between the tasks. Here is an example of how this might look:

```js
function createThrottler(delayMs) {
  const sleep = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayMs));
  let queue;
  
  return function (task) {
    queue = queue ? queue.then(sleep) : Promise.resolve();
    queue = queue.then(task);
    return queue;
  };
}

var symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];
const throttle = createThrottler(2000);

symbols.forEach((symbol, index) => {
  throttle(() => {
    // you code here
    console.log(index, symbol);
  });
});
```

This this will schedule the start of each tasks 2000 ms from the end of the previous task.

```
|> task 1 <|                           |> task 2 <|
           |<-------- 2000 ms -------->|
```

As requested in the comments, here is how you can combine the above with the code snippet of the question. This uses the first solution, but you could do the same for the second.

```
var symbols = ["ZRXBTC", "ETHBTC", "ETCBTC", "KAVABTC", "AEBTC"];

symbols.forEach((symbol, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
          Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
          High: parseFloat(d[2]),
          Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
          Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
          Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
          Timespan: 30,
        }
      });
      console.log(btcusdtdata);
      saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, index * 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently it looks pretty complex for me. Is there any chance that you can provide a full code example with your first code snippet?

Comment: @Hexycode I've added an example that that combines the solution with the question snippet in the answer.