# How to stop setTimeout inside a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, settimeout

This is a continue question from this thread - [setTimeout inside a loop, stops script from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464680/settimeout-inside-a-loop-stops-script-from-working)

I have a script which is receiving the data from API and stores it inside a MongoDB collection.
The problem is that `setTimeout()` is doesn't allowed the script to run second time. 
I'm 99.9% sure that the problem is especially in it.

Problem overview - [Watch Out When Using SetTimeout() in For Loop #JS](https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f)

**Problematic code area:**

```
const callIt = () => {


    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
            cnt++;
            if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000)  
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);

        })

};
```

This script is calling API and then it goes through array to receive symbols. How can I stop `setTimeout()` after it goes through whole array?

I was trying to add something like `clearTimeout(callIt)` doesn't work for me.

**EDIT1**

Error: - `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

**FULLCODE**

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");



var symbols = ["ZRXBTC",
    "LENDBTC",
    "AEBTC",
    "AIONBTC",
    "ALGOBTC",
    "ARDRBTC",];
let cnt = 0;
    const callIt = () => {
    fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
                return {
                    Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
                    High: parseFloat(d[2]),
                    Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
                    Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
                    Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
                    Timespan: 30,
                }
            });
            console.log(btcusdtdata);
            saveToDatebase(btcusdtdata);
            cnt++;
            if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);

        })

};
const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', callIt)

const saveToDatebase = function(BTCdata) {

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('CryptoCurrencies');
        const myobj = { Name: symbols[cnt - 1], Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
        dbo.collection(`${symbols[cnt - 1]}`).insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });

};
```

Comment: wouldn't the `if (cnt < symbols.length)` take care of stopping the script? why do you need an extra `clearTimeout` for?

Comment: @Tibebes.M Basically. The script is working first time, but gives me an error when It's supposed to start second time. I'll edit main question with full code example.

Comment: `timer = setTimeout(); ... clearTimeout(timer)` - you are passing callback instead of timeout index

Comment: "gives me an error when It's supposed to start" - always, always include error details.

Comment: @Justinas could you provide example cause when I try your code(maybe I do it wrongly) it's starts script immediately but it suppose to start working every hour with node-schedule package

Comment: The problem not with the `setTimeout()`. "Watch Out When Using SetTimeout() in For Loop #JS"  this issue occurs only when you are referring variables inside the `setTimeout()`. There is something wrong with the data you are getting from the service. check what your getting from the service on the second call.

Comment: @GirishSasidharang let's say i have 15 minutes delay with node-schedule. Why it's starts and working on a first time without any problem but when another 15minutes passed and script suppose to start working again, it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The script I wrote for you in the other post which you call problematic, works without any clearTimeout - something else is going on

You could MOVE the `if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000);` just after `db.close();` if you want

```js
const symbols = ["ZRXBTC",
"LENDBTC",
"AEBTC",
"AIONBTC",
"ALGOBTC",
"ARDRBTC",];
cnt = 0
const callIt = () => {
  console.log(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbols[cnt]}&interval=30m&limit=1`)
  cnt++;
  if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000);
  else console.log("done!")
};
callIt()
```

Comment: This is going work for me as well. Take a look on edited question if you can.

Comment: You say the code above is problematic. I say it works as designed

Comment: You could add the `if (cnt < symbols.length) setTimeout(callIt, 3000);` just after `db.close();` if you want

Comment: I Added after `db.close();` doesn't work for me as well. Works first time, stops working second time.

Comment: TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216280/discussion-between-hexycode-and-mplungjan).